Summing a function involving modulo operator
I have been studying the following function: $$f(a,m,n)=\min\{(a\cdot2^{n}) \bmod m, m-((a\cdot2^{n}) \bmod m)\}$$
where $a$, $m$, and $n$ are non-negative integers such that $m$ is odd, $\gcd(a,m)=1$ and $a<m$.
It appears that for a fixed $a$, if we vary $n$ from $0$ onwards, we get a periodic pattern. Now define the following summatory function $$S(a,m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f(a,m,n)}{2^n}$$
For relatively small $a$ and $m$ we can generate the periodic sequence and calculate the sum. Is it possible to further simplify the sum so that we don't need to actually evaluate $f(a,m,n)$ for all $n$ until we get the period, in order to calculate $S(a,m)$?

@lulu I have edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out.
